# Fluent nHibernate: Create Index for multiple foreignkeys and another for one single foreign key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a table called "TableA". In this table there are two columns(foreign keys) called "ColA" and "ColB". I want to create two indexes. One for ColA and ColB, and another one just for ColB.
In SQL this can be done with this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableA_ColA_ColB] ON TableA
(
ColA ASC,
ColB ASC
)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableA_ColB] ON TableA
(
ColB ASC
)
```

In Fluent nHibernate to create one index for two columns i do it like that:

TableA - is of type `AutoMapping`

ColA/ColBExpression - is of type `Expression<Func<T, TRef>>`

```
TableA.References(ColAExpression).Index(indexName);
TableA.References(ColBExpression).Index(indexName);
```

Now if I try to set another index for ColB I try to do it like this:

```
TableA.References(ColBExpression).Index(otherIndexName);
```

The problem is that the index gets overwritten instead of joined, and I get a mapping like this:

```
<many-to-one class="ColB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" foreign-key="Fk_TableA_TableB_ColB" name="ColB">
  <column name="ColBId" index="IX_TableA_ColB" />
</many-to-one>
```

Is there a way to use Fluent nHibernate to create a mapping like below?

```
<many-to-one class="ColB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" foreign-key="Fk_TableA_TableB_ColB" name="ColB">
  <column name="ColBId" index="IX_TableA_ColB, IX_TableA_ColA_ColB" />
</many-to-one>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this kind of thing using derivatives of `AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject`:

```
public class SetIdDefaultsAuxiliaryDatabaseObject : AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject
{
    public override string SqlCreateString(
        Dialect dialect,
        IMapping p,
        string defaultCatalog,
        string defaultSchema)
    {
        return
            $"ALTER TABLE {nameof(Customer)} ADD DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SQ_{nameof(Customer)} FOR {nameof(Customer)}Id;"
    }

    public override string SqlDropString(
        Dialect dialect,
        string defaultCatalog,
        string defaultSchema)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
 }
```

...and then wiring them into my `SessionFactory` creation:

```
Fluently
    .Configure(Config)
    .Mappings(
        m => 
            m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomerMap>()
                .Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => "Id"), DefaultLazy.Always(), ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"))
                .Conventions.Add(new ForeignKeyConvention()))
    .ExposeConfiguration(
        config =>
        {
            Assembly
               .GetExecutingAssembly()
               .GetTypes()
               .Where(t => typeof(AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject).IsAssignableFrom(t))
               .ForEach(t => config.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IAuxiliaryDatabaseObject));
        })
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

You could add your extra index via an `AuxiliaryDatabaseObject`.